# Variance and Variograms: Sigma?

Tags: r, spatial, geostatistics, variogram

Can someone please walk me through this morass of σ's?

There is a sigmasq in the summary output from geoR's likfit.  Really this is the one I'd like to know about.  I'm not clear which of all of the other σ's it is.  A variance? A different parameter?

nmle's variogram calls sigma "an optional numeric value used as the height of a horizontal line displayed in the plot. Can be used to represent the process standard deviation. Default is NULL, implying that no horizontal line is drawn. "  I thought this was phi.

geoR variofit's documentation calls it a "partial sill" and says to set a starting value.  (I'm also not quite conceptually clear on what variofit is modelling differently from likfit.)

Diggle & Ribiero (Model-Based Geostatistics) calls σ^2 "signal variance." Is that the same sigma? Later (p. 33), they say σ^2 is the value the (?expectation of the) vij's approach as the distance xi-xj grows, and that uncorrelated yi's have an expectation of σ^2.